# convertidor de monedas/divisas en php

Tags: php

quiero convertir de dólares a pesos colombianos en PHP y que esto quede guardado en una variable para usarlo en la api de paypal, he investigado y probando y usé esta página

https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/

Aquí un código de ejemplo:

```
<?php



function convertCurrency($amount, $from_currency, $to_currency)
{
    $apikey = '';

    $from_Currency = urlencode($from_currency);
    $to_Currency = urlencode($to_currency);
    $query =  "{$from_Currency}_{$to_Currency}";

    // URL para solicitar los datos
    $json = file_get_contents("https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q={$query}&compact=ultra&apiKey={$apikey}");
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);

    $val = floatval($obj["$query"]);


    $totalc = $val * $amount;
    return number_format($totalc, 0, '', '');
}

//uncomment to test
echo "1 USD equivale a ";
echo convertCurrency(1, 'USD', 'COP');
echo " COP";
?>
```

pero por alguna razón que no comprendo, al día siguiente se cayó el servidor o algo así y ahora me toca utilizar otra cosa.
investigando supe también que google tiene una api pero de tantos blogs que he leído no me queda claro cómo hacer la implementación, ¿alguien por favor puede ayudarme?

Comment: Revisa las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3139879/5587982).

Comment: Deberías borrar la apikey del ejemplo.

Comment: Ya no uso esa apikey pero weno